# Why won't my <input> text box fit inside my modal <div>?

Tags: html, css, input, modal-dialog

I created a modal with an input box, however, it doesn't seem to fit properly or look correct. Note: There's a lot here because I could only replicate the issue with the entire webpage code.
Here's the CSS for the input box:

```
input[type=text], input[type=password] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Here's a JSFiddle showcasing it:
https://jsfiddle.net/bkgt3av8/

Edit: Seems to be something in my style.css file. Here's what's there:

```
.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #041d44;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}
#grid {
   overflow-y: hidden;
   width: 100%;
}
    .bottomleft {
    position: absolute;
}
a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
}
#section04 a {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
#section04 a span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  margin-left: -12px;
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-animation: sdb04 2s infinite;
  animation: sdb04 2s infinite;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
@-webkit-keyframes sdb04 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, 0);
  }
  20% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-10px, 10px);
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, 0);
  }
}
@keyframes sdb04 {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, 0);
  }
  20% {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-10px, 10px);
  }
  40% {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, 0);
  }
}
.coolbutton {
  color: white;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border-color: #ccc;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 6px 12px;
}
.info {
  padding: 20px;
}
.error {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}
#container {
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
}

#disqus_thread {
    width:1000px;

}
.center {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Any help identifying what it is would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you include a [mcve] to your question? if the fiddle link goes down, the question becomes incomplete and, thus, impossible to answer

Comment: Well, the issue is that I'm not sure where the issue is, all I seem to know is that it's inside my style.css file. Basically, it stretches my <input> out. Realizing that it's my style.css narrows it down. The JSFiddle isn't very necessary nor is the minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Well, if we can't reproduce the issue, how can we solve it? - you need to narrow it down to the most basic example that makes the issue appear. A [mcve] is absolutely necessary as it will narrow it down from a myriad of possibilities and, thus, narrow it down to a handful of possible solutions - help us, help you.

Comment: FWIW, I grabbed your code and ran it and was not able to reproduce it, so what you are seeing is not because of the code you provided above.

Comment: oh. strange. I tried removing my style.css file and It worked fine. So problem solved?

Comment: I dunno, you tell me ;) - I couldn't tell you because I have not been able to troubleshoot it due to a lack of a [mcve] :D

Comment: Glad to hear you solve the issue, now the next step is to figure out which element of your `style.css` file is modifying (and affecting) the input to the point that it behaves poorly

Comment: I have a good feeling that it's either #container or .center